# Получить из Edittext значение Int

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Приветствую.

Возникла проблема, у меня есть `Edittext` я в него ввожу цифры (номера страниц), и хочу введенные данные передать во `ViewPager`, чего только не перепробовал, не рабоает.

```
    Button select_num_page = (Button) findViewById(R.id.select_num_page);

    EditText num_page = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num_page);

    final int str = Integer.parseInt(num_page.getText().toString());

    select_num_page.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            my_view_pager.setCurrentItem(str);
        }
    });
```

Приложение падает и выдает ошибку:

```
Process: jmapps.questions200, PID: 8115                                                                 
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
```

Пытался преобразовать в Int на входе, то есть в методе `setCurrentItem` все равно не работает. Также в `inputType` в `Edittext` указывал и `number` и все остальное. Если я вместо `str` поставлю номер нужной страницы, например так:

```
my_view_pager.setCurrentItem(10);
```

То все работает. Вопрос: Как правильно получить вводимые в `Edittext` цифры, преобразовать их в Int и передать во `Viewpager` в методе `onClick` кнопки `select_name_page`?

Comment: Конкретно что показывает деббагер?

Comment: Забирайте текст из `EditText`'a непосредственно в `onClick`. Вы его берёте из пустого, только что созданного.

Comment: @woesss Выведите ваше сообщение в ответы, я отмечу как правильный ответ. Все работает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Забирайте текст из EditText'a непосредственно в onClick. Вы его берёте из пустого, только что созданного.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего в строке есть посторонние символы, попробуйте так:

```
final int str = Integer.parseInt(num_page.getText().toString().trim());
```

Comment: Пробелы по бокам это посторонние символы?